Multiple summation signs simplication
I have considered a function that is defined by four summation signs. Ideally, I would like to express this function in terms of one summation sign. I have looked into multi-index notation but am unsure of how to correctly apply it to this specific case. The function is given by
$$
\sum_{i=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{l=0}^\infty \frac{t^{i+j+k+l}}{i!\,j!\,k!\,l!}=\sum_{\alpha=0}^\infty \frac{t^\beta}{\gamma},
$$
where it remains to find $\alpha,\beta$ and $\gamma$. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Where is $\alpha$ in the rhs ?

Here, $\alpha$ would represent the summation indices on the lhs.

I do not see any $\alpha$ in lhs and rhs

You have :
$$
\sum_{i=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{l=0}^\infty \frac{t^{i+j+k+l}}{i!\,j!\,k!\,l!} = \sum_{\alpha\in\Bbb{N}^4} \frac{t^\alpha}{\alpha!} = e^{4t},
$$
given that $t^\alpha = t^{\alpha_1}t^{\alpha_2}t^{\alpha_3}t^{\alpha_4}$ and $\alpha! = \alpha_1!\alpha_2!\alpha_3!\alpha_4!$.
